# How to disable TextView automatic text formating for certain characters?

Tags: java, android, text, formatting, textview

I have textview with droid sans mono font. Max line lenght is 10 characters. gettin it by this function.

> this.getPaint().breakText(FULLTEXT, 0, 100, true, this.getWidth(), null);

I want lines always full if there is text and not the break halfway or something similar.
If I am using only normal characters like numbers and letters its working but for characters like "." or "," in certain situations the line break.

For example: if i have line:

```
"0123456789" or ".012345678"
```

tv is working as i want.. line is full..but with input:

```
"Y.012345678"
```

the line break this way:

```
".xxxxxxxxx"
"012345678Y"
```

where x are empty spaces.

i want to have multiline, i just dont want empty spaces (just in last line)

If i insert two special character like:

```
"01234\\.789"
```

its start breaking halfway if line is full. how i understand it, textview is breaking sentences which are too long for line.

Curently i am inputing different chareacter without this behaviour, but i would be happy if i didn't need too do this. (too much corections need too be done and its messy)

I noticed that descripted behaviour is not on every android version. I have devices with android 2.3.6, 4.0.4 and kindle fire version. I don't have problem on 2.3.6.

Is there a way how to disable this textview behaviour? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

is the property of textview and edittext which will keep the text on single line. if length of string is too big then text will be truncated but will never go on next line.

Comment: i want to have multiline textview. i am using android:inputType="textMultiLine" i just want to have white spaces only in last line.